# On click of Action button ,Display set of fields every time this button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onclick

I have an action button. when i click it it should open a set of fields in a div. again i click this action button it should display div with same contents and fields below the previous one.Every time the user clicks a new div with the same fields should be created and these data has to be captured while clicking save button.

Comment: What is the question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: May be a victim of viewstate?

Comment: Dude, why are you posting far too broad questions that can never lead you to the answers you want? You need to post precisely concise code snippet you have tried.

Comment: i have page where an action button is there.When i click some fields are displayed.this fields should be displayed every time i click but with a condition that field that were displayed by button click shouldnt be refreshed . I am new to asp .net

Comment: ChemicalX check my answer.(used Jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your asked context but not completely
Here i am answering you with some guess work

```
<button type="button" id="createFields" name="createFields">Click Me!</button>
```

At script/jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#createFields").click(function () {
   ("div").append(function(){ "return "<b>html fields inside </b>";//append something here....doing this might complete your task

    });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.i guess this is what i wanted

Comment: Every time i click this button the fields inside the div will be again displayed without over writing the previous ones?

Comment: Than you very much for encouraging.

Comment: instead of html field when i add asp:Textbox it throws an error.Cant asp controls not be added?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. Ok use this syntex append($('div')); and at div use asp:....